# Database config for Django and SQL Server - escaping the host

Tags: python, sql-server, django, escaping

I have setup my Django app to use Microsoft SQL Server database. This is my database config.

```
 DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': "reporting",
        'HOST': '192.168.192.225\SQL2022;',
        'PORT': 1433,
        'USER': "sa",
        'PASSWORD': "Root_1421",
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

The SQL Server database is installed on my desktop machine and `DESKTOP-RC52TD0\SQL2022` is the host\instance name. When print my config, I get the following.

```
{'default': {'ENGINE': 'mssql', 'NAME': 'reporting', 'HOST': 'DESKTOP-RC52TD0\\SQL2022', 'USER': 'sa', 'PASSWORD': 'Root_1421', 'OPTIONS': {'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'}}}
```

Notice that in HOST, the value has two slashes added to it, which is causing my app to not be able to connect to the database. I believe this is because of Python escaping feature for strings. How do can I escape so that I end up with a single slash and not double? As I am getting the following error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I've tried the following and still same result:

1. `r'DESKTOP-RC52TD0\SQL2022'`
2. `'DESKTOP-RC52TD0\\SQL2022'`
3. `r'DESKTOP-RC52TD0\SQL2022'`

Any ideas how I can escape in the context of a dictionary. In a string adding double slash `\\` works but not when used in a dictionary.

I am running the app using docker-compose.

```
version: '3'

services:
  # sqlserver:
  #   image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
  #   hostname: 'sqlserver'
  #   environment:
  #     ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
  #     MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: 'P@55w0rd'
  #   ports:
  #     - '1433:1433'
  #   volumes:
  #     - sqlserver-data:/var/opt/mssql
  web:
    image: landsoft/reporting-api
    network_mode: host
    build:
      context: ./app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST="DESKTOP-RC52TD0\SQL2022"
      - DB_NAME=reporting
      - DB_USER=sa
      - DB_PASSWORD=Root_1421
      - DB_PORT=1433
    # depends_on:
    #   - sqlserver
    
# volumes:
#   sqlserver-data:
#     driver: local
```

Comment: _Notice that in HOST, the value has two slashes added to it_ No it doesn't.  That is Python's special way of printing strings that contain backslashes.  That hostname only has one backslash.

Comment: _which is causing my app to not be able to connect to the database_ Please show us the actual error message.

Comment: This is the error message..

django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)').

I assumed it was because of the double slash (which appears on print)..
My username and password is correct.

Comment: Do you have the correct database port open in the docker container, so that it can connect?  I only see port 8000 open.

Comment: The ports are fine..

Comment: I tried using the driver directly, and it works:

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.192.225\SQL2022;DATABASE=reporting;PORT=1433;UID=sa;PWD=Root_1421').

But from django i get the login timeout expired error still

Comment: What is `env()`?  Is that a django thing?

Comment: Thats just for loading environment variables. The environment variables are loading fine..Now im placing the db connection explicitly not loading from environment.

Comment: I used the pyodbc driver directly along with database configuration, and successfully connected. But from django, the error still persists.

Comment: Consider using either an instance name __or__ a port number... not both. TBH I'd look up the assigned port number of the SQL2022 instance in SQL Server Configuration Manager and use that, as it will be faster and more reliable than trying to do instance name resolution over the UDP-based SSRP request to the SQL Browser service on the target machine.

Comment: I tested the django app with docker image of the sql server (mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server) and the integration works. But it just seems to not be working with my sql server installed on my local pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.

In the `DATABASES` configuration, i changed the `HOST` to use the ip address and port instead of the instance name. I also left the `PORT' blank.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': 'reporting',
        'HOST': '192.168.211.225,56985', # use ip with port separated by comma
        'PORT': '', # left blank
        'USER': '...username..',
        'PASSWORD': '..password..',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https python3 python3-pip python3-venv python-dev locales nano
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2

# ODBC 17 DEPENDENCIES
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install msodbcsql17 freetds-dev tdsodbc

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install mssql-tools
# Add the necessary commands for setting up the environment
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"

RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/


RUN python3 -m venv /venv
ENV PATH="/venv/bin:$PATH"
RUN /venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt -v

ADD . /code/

RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen
RUN locale-gen
```

This is my requirements.txt file..

```
Django==3.2.23
mssql-django==1.3
djangorestframework>=3.12.4,<=3.13
drf-spectacular>=0.15.1,<=0.16
Pillow>=8.2.0,<=8.3.0
django-environ>=0.11.2,<=0.12
```

Hopefully it helps someone facing similar problem..